# Has or have in a question

Tags: grammar, tense

Does she have a car ? Or does she has a car ?

What is the difference between these two questions ?

What do they mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be said that above question refers to grammatical subject and rules in English lang. When someone is going to ask a question concerning third person, he or she does have something or they want to do something, in the question form "Does" must be used with "have" because of existence of "Does", "has" should be ommited to obbey the grammatical rules as English speakers do.
of course sometimes we have got exceptions in every lang.
at last I do not think there is a diffrence except the grammatical form.